# How Unity launcher trashbin icon works?

Tags: 16.04, icons, trash

Unity launcher panel trashbin icon can be updated (full icon to empty icon) when emptying to trash bin. The trash bin icon is refreshed althought application is running.

How to programming this kind of functionality for icon?
Any short ideas?

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

br. MTi